# R: How to collapse multiple observations of an ordered factor within a data frame?

Tags: r, data-manipulation, categorical-data, ordinal

DISCLAIMER:  I'm not sure "collapse" is quite the right term for this operation.  If there's a more appropriate term, I'm all ears.

I have data on symptom severity for several hundred patients from multiple observations over time. Severity is defined on an ordinal scale.  Here's a simplified example:

```
# Create example dataset
example.dat <- data.frame(
  ID = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4),  # patient ID numbers
  Time = c("T1", "T2", "T3", "T1", "T2", "T3",  # times at which data were collected
           "T1", "T2", "T3", "T1", "T2", "T3"),
  Severity = c("Mild", "Moderate", "Mild",  # severity of symptoms
          "Severe", "Severe", "Moderate",
          "None", NA, "None",
          "Moderate", "Moderate", "Mild")
)

# Specify the order of the factor levels
example.dat$Severity <- ordered(example.dat$Severity,
                                levels = c("None",
                                           "Mild",
                                           "Moderate",
                                           "Severe")
                                )

example.dat
```

The resulting data frame looks like this:

```
   ID Time Severity
1   1   T1     Mild
2   1   T2 Moderate
3   1   T3     Mild
4   2   T1   Severe
5   2   T2   Severe
6   2   T3 Moderate
7   3   T1     None
8   3   T2     <NA>
9   3   T3     None
10  4   T1 Moderate
11  4   T2 Moderate
12  4   T3     Mild
```

I would like to create a new column containing the most severe symptoms (i.e. the highest level of the ordered factor) observed for each ID, which would look like this:

```
   ID Time Severity    Worst
1   1   T1     Mild Moderate
2   1   T2 Moderate Moderate
3   1   T3     Mild Moderate
4   2   T1   Severe   Severe
5   2   T2   Severe   Severe
6   2   T3 Moderate   Severe
7   3   T1     None     None
8   3   T2     <NA>     None
9   3   T3     None     None
10  4   T1 Moderate Moderate
11  4   T2 Moderate Moderate
12  4   T3     Mild Moderate
```

From there, I can easily subset to create this data frame, which includes, for each ID, the time of the most recent observation and the worst symptoms reported during the study period:

```
   ID Time    Worst
3   1   T3 Moderate
6   2   T3   Severe
9   3   T3     None
12  4   T3 Moderate
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

You can find the maximum / most severe symptom by id using `ave`

```
example.dat$Worst <- ave(example.dat$Severity, example.dat$ID, 
                                      FUN = function(i) max(i, na.rm=TRUE))
```

The `na.rm` option is used due to the missing values for some ID

You can then subset to only keep the most recent time.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution using the `aggregate` function in R:

```
example.dat <- data.frame(
ID = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4),  # patient ID numbers
Time = c("T1", "T2", "T3", "T1", "T2", "T3",  # times at which data were collected
       "T1", "T2", "T3", "T1", "T2", "T3"),
Severity = c("Mild", "Moderate", "Mild",  # severity of symptoms
      "Severe", "Severe", "Moderate",
      "None", NA, "None",
      "Moderate", "Moderate", "Mild")
)

# Specify the order of the factor levels
example.dat$Severity <- ordered(example.dat$Severity,
                            levels = c("None",
                                       "Mild",
                                       "Moderate",
                                       "Severe")
                            )


new <- aggregate(Severity ~ ID , data = example.dat, FUN = max)
names(new)[names(new) == "Severity"] <- "Worst"
(final <- merge(example.dat, new))
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
 res <- example.dat %>%
 group_by(ID) %>% 
 mutate(Worst=Severity[which.max(Severity)])

res
#Source: local data frame [12 x 4]
# Groups: ID

#    ID Time Severity    Worst
# 1   1   T1     Mild Moderate
# 2   1   T2 Moderate Moderate
# 3   1   T3     Mild Moderate
# 4   2   T1   Severe   Severe
# 5   2   T2   Severe   Severe
# 6   2   T3 Moderate   Severe
# 7   3   T1     None     None
# 8   3   T2       NA     None
# 9   3   T3     None     None
# 10  4   T1 Moderate Moderate
# 11  4   T2 Moderate Moderate
# 12  4   T3     Mild Moderate

 filter(res, Time=="T3") %>% select(-Severity)
#Source: local data frame [4 x 4]
#Groups: ID
#   ID Time    Worst
# 1  1   T3 Moderate
# 2  2   T3   Severe
# 3  3   T3     None
# 4  4   T3 Moderate
```

Or `data.table`

```
library(data.table) ## 1.9.3
setDT(example.dat)[,Worst := Severity[which.max(Severity)], by=ID]    
example.dat
```

You can get the latest version, 1.9.3 from [here](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table). If instead you'd like to use the CRAN version 1.9.2, then there's a tiny bug with factors which we'll have to take care of, which has been fixed in 1.9.3:

```
library(data.table) ## 1.9.2 from CRAN
setDT(example.dat)[, Worst := as.character(Severity)]
example.dat[, Worst := Worst[which.max(Severity)], by=ID]
```

---

Assuming that the data set is already ordered by `ID,Time`, this'll get you the final solution directly:

```
require(data.table) ## 1.9.3
setDT(example.dat)[, list(Time=Time[.N], Worst=Severity[which.max(Severity)]), by=ID]
#    ID Time    Worst
# 1:  1   T3 Moderate
# 2:  2   T3   Severe
# 3:  3   T3     None
# 4:  4   T3 Moderate
```

`setDT` converts the data.frame to data.table. Then, we group by `ID` and get the last value of `Time` in that group using `.N` which is an integer vector of length 1 holding the number of observations in that group. And similarly we subset the corresponding maximum `Severity`.

Comment: @Arun, thanks for the edit.  But, in the first case, I get for the `Worst` column numbers (factor converted to numeric).example.dat$Worst
 #[1] 3 3 3 4 4 4 1 1 1 3 3 3

Comment: That's a bug in just 1.9.2 version. It's been fixed now. Just edited the version in. Even then, it's inefficient to convert to `character` on each group, better to do it once up front.

Comment: @Arun, I don't think it is practical to show a 1.9.3 solution, because the OP won't even know where to get it from without proper instrucitons

Comment: @DavidArenburg, akrun, edited 1.9.2 version in as well. Hope it's all good now.